# How to redirect information after successful php if statement in ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

PHP As you can see in the below PHP code I am trying the redirect the user but I am struggling to do it in jquery.

What I want is if login statement is a success login_success then the user will redirect on myprofile.php but nothing happened.

```
if($query)
{

   $num=mysqli_fetch_array($query); //fetching all matching records

   if($num > 0) 
   {
      //if record found        
      $_SESSION["loggedin"] = TRUE;       

      $_SESSION['cid']=$num['cid'];

      echo  "login_success";

   }
   else
   {
      echo "invalid email or password.";
   }
 }
 else
 {
   echo "something went wrong!";
 }
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({                         
 url:"sql/login_process.php",                         
 method:"POST",                       
 data:$('#login_form').serialize(),  
 beforeSend:function()
 {   
   $('#login_response').html('<span class="text-info"><i class="fas fa-spinner"></i> Loading response...</span>');  
 },
 success:function(data)
 {                              
   $('form').trigger("reset"); 
   $('#login_response').fadeIn().html(data);
   setTimeout(function(){
 
     $('#login_response').fadeOut("slow");
  }, 7000);

  if(data == "login_success") location.href = "http://www.example.
```

Comment: If you want to redirect someone after the request then there is no point in using AJAX...the whole purpose of ajax is to allow you avoid needing to post back, refresh, redirect etc, and instead to stay on the same page

Comment: Try adding error function to Ajax and then see console for errors

Answer (score -1):

On the line `if(data == "login_success") location.href = "http://www.example.` you need to change to `if(data == "login_success") location.assign('<link to your profile page>')`.